# how to make changes appear instantly in the user interface?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, user-interface, xamarin.android

sorry for my bad English . i am new  to xamarin android, i am facing a problem when trying to make changes in the user interface.
For example last time i tried to change the background of a button when clicking it. But this doesn't happen until the end of the the click method.

```
    private void MainActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ((Button)(sender)).SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background);

        //other code to run

    }
```

I tried to do it in RunOnUiThread and BeginInvokeOnMainThread but it didn't work either.
When debugging,i found that it actually  made the change instantly but it does not appear on the app
until the method is done.Also there is an event when the button state ispressed =true,and the button stay highlighted even after release,it stuck like that until the end of the method MainActivity_Click.
Sorry again for my bad English. Solutions?

Comment: Separate code which doesnt cause UI changes and try running them on Non-UI thread/Task. Thats the only way to responsive UI's

Comment: I don't know much about xamarin, but an android UI will only change when it is repainted by the main thread. Which can only happen if the thread is not blocked.

Comment: You need to focus this question a bit more. It is too general. Try following a tutorial and provide a mimum working example once you have it and the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your "other code to run" block the thread,you could try to use asynchronous tasks to handle these time-consuming operations.

try below :

```
private void MainActivity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ((Button)(sender)).SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background);

    DoAsyncTask();

}


public async void DoAsyncTask()
{

  await Task.Run(() =>
   {
     //other code to run
   });

}
```

You could look at [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)